# In Selenium, how can I locate second <td> element in <tr> tag?

Tags: python, html, selenium

I would like to locate second **td** element in **tr** tag which has 4 **td** tags.
This is **HTML** code that I want to get from there.

```
<tr>
    <td width="10%" class="cell">&nsp;</td>
    <td class="cell" width="40%">Sports</td>
    <td class="cell rgt" width="40%">-29.94</td>
    <td width="10%" class="cell">&nsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
    <td class="cell">Casino</td>
    <td class="cell rgt">464.22</td>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
    <td class="cell">Poker</td>
    <td class="cell rgt">14.29</td>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
    <td class="cell">Games / Bingo</td>
    <td class="cell rgt">145.17</td>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
    <td class="cell b">Total</td>
    <td class="cell b rgt">593.75</td>
    <td class="cell b">&nsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c3">
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
    <td class="cell b">Withdrawals to date</td>
    <td class="cell b rgt">0.00</td>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr class="c3">
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
    <td class="cell b">Balance</td>
    <td class="cell b rgt">593.75</td>
    <td class="cell">&nsp;</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to get data like

```
Sports, -29.94
Casino, 434.22
Poker, 14.29
Games / Bingo, 145.17
Total, 593.75
Withdrawals to date, 0.00
Balance, 593.75
```

This is the snippet code I've made in order to get data.

```
bet365 = webdriver.Chrome()
bet365.get("https://www.abcde.com")
...
for incomes in bet365.find_elements_by_class_name("rgt"):
    if incomes.text != "Close Window":
        print(incomes.text)
        Earning = incomes.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]")
        print(Earning.text)
```

As you can see I can get all numbers from **HTML** code such as

```
-29.94
464.22
14.29
145.17
593.75
0.00
593.75
```

But I can't get **Sports, Casino** and so on.

How can I get them automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have made a minor mistake.

Replace

```
Earning = incomes.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]")
```

with

```
Earning = incomes.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath(".//td[2]")
```

There should be a "." in front of "td" so that the driver doesn't search the element throughout the HTML page. The element should be searched from the current element.

Comment: You should be able to combine the two `find_*`s into one XPath, `incomes.find_element_by_xpath("./../td[2]")`. `.` starts from the current context, `/..` goes up one to the parent element, and then `/.td[2]` goes down to the 2nd `td` element.

Answer (score 1):

As the td you want to get always appears before the one you got, you can try to get preceding sibling like this:

```
incomes.find_element_by_xpath('..').find_element_by_xpath("//td[2]/preceding-sibling::td")
```